# Calculate amicable numbers efficiently to a very high upper limit in java

Tags: java, performance

I have a program that computes amicable pairs of numbers up to a certain limit and prints them out to Stdout.  FYI - two numbers are amicable if each is equal to the sum of the proper divisors of the other (for example, 220 and 284).

My program works fine for the first 8 or so pairs, but the problem is when the limit gets to a very high number e.g 5 million it becomes very slow. Is there a way to optimize this so that it computes much faster?
Here is my code

```
public class Amicable{
    private static int num1, num2, limit = 5000000;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 1; i < limit;i++){
            num1= sumOfDivisors(i);
            num2 = sumOfDivisors(i)
            if(num1 == num2){
                    System.out.println(num2 + " " + num1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static int sumOfDivisors(int n){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=n/2;i++){
            if(n%i==0){
                sum =sum+i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought you could use recursion for even numbers - keep dividing in half until it's not a even number .. e.g. 220 -> 110 -> 55, so work out the factors for 55, and 2x55, and 4x55 [NOT INCLUDED BY DEFINITION]..  I guess could do the same thing for other primes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the innermost loop efficient.

```
static int sumOfDivisors(int n) {
    int sum = 1;
    int max = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    if (n > 1 && max * max == n) // in case of n is perfect square number
        sum -= max;
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; ++i)
        if (n % i == 0)
            sum += i + n / i;
    return sum;
}
```

If `n` = 220, it is divisible by 2, so you can add 2 and 110 to the sum at the same time. However, if `n` is a perfect square number, for example `n` = 100, it is divisible by 10, but if 10 and 10 are added, they will duplicate, so subtract it in advance.

output for limit =2000000:

```
220 284
1184 1210
2620 2924
5020 5564
6232 6368
10744 10856
12285 14595
17296 18416
63020 76084
66928 66992
.....
1468324 1749212
1511930 1598470
1669910 2062570
1798875 1870245
```

It took 7 seconds on my PC.

Comment: Thanks! this worked, but say that I didnt want to include 1 as a proper divisor would I simply change sum to 0. Would it still send back numbers with the same sum of proper divisors without 1 counting as a proper divisor?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the statement of "if(i<num1)" to "if(i<num1 || num1<limit)".

Comment: Except that i < limit because of the for-statement conditions.

Comment: sorry, I spelled wrong, it should be "num1<limt" and I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Then to make this a good answer, please explain why this will improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more efficient and faster approach.

Inside sumOfDivisors:

- Start iteration from 2. (no a big deal) and add 1 during return time with sum as 1 is also a divisor.
- Modify loop termination logic, i <= Math.sqrt(n).

  For any number ‘num’ all its divisors are always less than and equal to ‘num/2’ and all prime factors are always less than and equal to sqrt(num).
- If n%i == 0, then check, both divisors are are equal or not. If equal, take one if not equal then take both one.

```
private static int sumOfDivisors(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    int sqrt = Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            if(i == (n/i))
                sum = sum + i;
            else
                sum += (i+ n/i);
        }
    }
    return sum+1;
}
```

Comment: It is inefficient to calculate `Math.sqrt(n)` for each loop.

Comment: n is different for each loop, so how can we manage it? Though Math.sqrt is costly, it reduces lots of unnecessary operations, and overall performance increases. Yes, we can memorize sqrt value, this can improve its performance.

Comment: As this code is written, `n` has the same value for each iteration of the loop.  Therefore, replace with `int i = 2, m = (int) Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i <= m; i++` to avoid the cost of repeatedly computing the square root of `n`.

Comment: Thanks, both of you for this improvement, I have updated my code block.